# How to troubleshoot es6 module dependencies?

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs, refluxjs, es6-module-loader

**I am developing a React & `Reflux` app, which is bundled by `webpack` with `babel-loader` (v6), and I am experiencing es6 modules dependencies issues**

For example, I have a component that use the reflux `.connect()` mixin :

```
import MyStore from '../stores/my-store';

const Component = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Reflux.connect(MyStore)]
});
```

When I import all modules individually in each file like this, everything's fine.

I then tried to improve my code by using deconstructed import statements :

...in a component :

```
//import One from '../js/one';
//import Two from '../js/two';
//import Three from '../js/three';
import { One, Two, Three } from '../js'; // Instead
```

...and in `js/index.js` :

```
import One from './one';
import Two from './two';
import Three from './three';

export { One, Two, Three };
```

App source code files are more concise using the above technique, because I can import all components in one `import` line.

**But when I use this, some dependencies end up beeing `undefined` when I use them**

If I use the same updated example...

```
//import MyStore from '../stores/my-store';
import { MyStore } from '../stores'; // Instead

const Component = React.createClass({
    mixins: [Reflux.connect(MyStore)]
});
```

...`MyStore` parameter ends up `undefined` in `Reflux.connect` method.

I tried to troubleshoot in the debugger, but I'm not really aware of what's going on with the `__webpack_require__(xxx)` statements in the generated bundle. There must be a circular dependency that `babel-loader` or webpack require could not figure out when there are the `index.js` files re-exporting individual modules.

**Do you know any tool that can help me figure this out? I tried `madge` but it does not work with es6 modules, and I could not find anything that would tell me where anything is wrong**

Comment: Are you introducing circular dependencies with this technique?

Comment: I don't know, I guess there are already circular dependencies in my app, but they are not a problem *per se*, it's well managed by es6 loader. This is the fact of having bundled all stores, all components, etc, in index.js files that re-exports them, that causes the issue. I am not able to see why or how, hence my question.

Comment: To be clear : I don't know how to easily analyse/visualise my app module dependencies :)

Comment: @Pandaiolo [Analyse tool](https://webpack.github.io/analyse/) can do that.  You need to do something like `webpack --profile --json > stats.json` to get the file the tool expects.

Comment: @bebraw thanks, great tool! But even excluding babel polyfills, I have like 600 modules in my bundle, so the visualization screen is slow and useless. Any way to specifically spot circular or problematic dependencies ?

Comment: @Pandaiolo I'm not sure if there's anything specific for that. I would probably start by eliminating files from the project to pinpoint the culprit. You could also try setting up a `stores` [resolve.alias](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-alias). Maybe that would help.

Answer (score 2):

In order to get extended info about build, run:

```
webpack --profile --display-modules --display-reasons
```

It will give you bunch of information for optimisation/profiling.

Comment: Thanks, I would add the `--json` switch proposed by @bebraw which is really useful, however, for a large scale app, while it gives more insight on the bundle, it does not identify runtime dependencies issues

Answer (score 0):

> `import` statement is used to import functions, objects or primitives that have been exported from an external module.

As per MDN doc, you can import the Modules not the directory.

```
import name from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";
import { member } from "module-name";
import { member as alias } from "module-name";
import { member1 , member2 } from "module-name";
import { member1 , member2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
import defaultMember, { member [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
import defaultMember, * as alias from "module-name";
import defaultMember from "module-name";
import "module-name";
```

Reference URL:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
http://es6-features.org/#ValueExportImport
https://github.com/lukehoban/es6features#modules
http://www.2ality.com/2014/09/es6-modules-final.html

As a workaround keep one file as `base.js` and include all your 3 files.

Comment: I loaded Chrome Canary and this repo, but I realized it does not use `import` statements, instead every file is loaded with `<script>`tags in index.html. Anyhow, would Chrome 49+ load files imported using `import`? What about `npm` modules? Will the dev tools help me in troubleshooting my module dependency issue?

Comment: @Pandaiolo, Your current issue is exist in import { One, Two, Three } from '../js'; right !

Comment: @Pandaiolo, updated new answer. please take a look at it.